# Match and split string with regex

Tags: c#, regex, split, match

I want to validate an input string against a regular expression and then split it.

The input string can be any combination of the letter A and letter A followed by an exclamation mark. For example these are valid input strings: A, A!, AA, AA!, A!A, A!A!, AAA, AAA!, AA!A, A!AA, ... Any other characters should yield an invalid match.

My code would probably look something like this:

```
public string[] SplitString(string s)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"...");
    if (!regex.IsMatch(s))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong input string!");
    }

    return regex.Split(s);
}
```

How should my regex look like?

Edit - some examples:

- input string "AAA", function should return an array of 3 strings ("A", "A", "A")
- input string "A!AAA!", function should return an array of 4 strings ("A!", "A", "A", "A!")
- input string "AA!b", function should throw an ArgumentException

Comment: Are you sure this isn't homework?

Comment: @James - and suppose it is, still a valid question. Anyway, such "meta" tags are discouraged.

Comment: Why would you use regex for that, sounds like overkill

Comment: @James - yeah, I'm sure. @H.B. - this is a simplified example, there could be more different letters, but each of them should be either alone or with exclamation mark at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem like a Regex is a good plan here. Have a look at this:

```
private bool ValidString(string myString)
{
    char[] validChars = new char[] { 'A', '!' };
    if (!myString.StartsWith("A"))
        return false;
    if (myString.Contains("!!"))
        return false;
    foreach (char c in myString)
    {
        if (!validChars.Contains(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private List<string> SplitMyString(string myString)
{
    List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
    if (ValidString(myString))
    {
        string resultString = "";
        foreach (char c in myString)
        {
            if (c == 'A')
                resultString += c;
            if (c == '!')
            {
                resultString += c;
                resultList.Add(string.Copy(resultString));
                resultString = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

The reason for Regex not being a good plan is that you can write the logic out in a few simple if-statements that compile and function a lot faster and cheaper. Also Regex isn't so good at repeating patterns for an unlimited length string. You'll either end up writing a long Regex or something illegible.

EDIT
At the end of my code you will either have a `List<string>` with the split input string like in your question. Or an empty `List<string>`. You can adjust it a little to throw an ArgumentException if that requirement is very important to you. Alternatively you can do a `Count` on the list to see if it was successful.

Comment: Yeah Regex may not be efficient for everything, but here A! can occur but not A!! or something like that. Your solution doesn't make that consideration.

Comment: @manojlds Fair enough, let me solve that .. hang on. One more little if. I reckon Regex is still slower here.

Comment: i thought that with regex I could simplify things, not complicate them :)

Comment: @_simon_ perhaps you can, but I'm curious what pattern you'll come up with. Personally I think Regex almost always makes things more complicated because it is hard to read (compared to a few if-statements). But if you can find a simple regex that does what you are after, then I'm curious to see it, and I will stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(A!|A)+$");
```

Edit:

Use something like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to play with Regular Expressions

Edit after comment:

Ok, you have made it a bit more clear what you want. Don't approach it like that. Because in what you are doing, you cannot expect to match the entire input and then split as it would be the entire input. Either use separate regular expression for the split part, or use groups to get the matched values.

Example:

```
        //Initial match part

        Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"(A!)|(A)");

        return regex2.Split(s);
```

And again, regular expressions are not always the answer. See how this might impact your application.

Comment: Doesn't work. Input string: "AAA!AA", regex.Split returns only one A instead of array A, A, A!, A, A.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A!]+$");
```

Comment: Nope A!!A would be valid which is not the case

Comment: Also, input string "AAA!AA", regex.Split returns 2 empty strings instead of an array "A", "A", "A!", "A", "A".

Answer (score 1):

`((A+!?)+)`

Try looking at Espresso http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm or Rad Software Regular Expression Designer http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/ for designing and testing RE's.

Comment: Nope, something like A!B would still match.

Comment: Also, input string "AAA!AA", regex.Split returns 4 items ("", "AAA!AA", "AA", "") instead of an array "A", "A", "A!", "A", "A".

Comment: @_simon_. While @manojlds is correct in that mine will pick up the A! part of A!B I need some clarification also. You said you want to validate an input string and **split it**. Does the string being validated **contain** the A! string variants along with other data or is it **exclusively** the "A!" string variants and if it contains anything else then none of the string is valid?  (Ex. "This is A! test.")

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I have a solution that satisfies all examples. I've had to break it into two regular expressions (which I don't like)...

```
public string[] SplitString(string s)
{
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A!]+$");
  if (!regex.IsMatch(s))
  {
      throw new ArgumentException("Wrong input string!");
  } 
  return Regex.Split(s, @"(A!?)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Note the use of linq - required to remove the empty matches.